# $P(1)+P(2)+...+P(n)=n^{7}+\lambda$ , $P(\lambda)=?$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

$\lambda \in\mathbb{R}$ and $P\in\mathbb{R}[X]$ a polynomial equation

$$P(1)+P(2)+...+P(n)=n^{7}+\lambda,n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$$

I need to find $P(\lambda)$.

I got $P(n)=n^{7}-(n-1)^{7}$ so $P(\lambda)=\lambda^{7}-(\lambda-1)^{7}$ but the right answer is $1.$How to continue ?

Comment: how can you say that the condition $P(n)=n^7-(n-1)^7$ $\textbf{for all natural numbers $n\in \mathbb{N}$}$ implies that $P(\lambda)=\lambda^7-(\lambda-1)^7$ for $\textbf{some arbitrary real number $\lambda$}$??

Comment: n is from N*.I didn't know that I was wrong

Comment: Yeah.. So, that was a wrong step... Try differently now..

Comment: I would try if you would give me a hint or something

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik but... If the polynomial $P(n) - (n^7 - (n-1)^7)$ has infinitely many zeros, then it is the zero polynomial.

Comment: @liaombro That is correct... I was trying to say  how would some thing true for $\textbf{so many}$ natural numbers implies the same statement is true for $\textbf{some real number}$...

Comment: Can you check if you have posted the question correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You've calculated $P(x)$ right, so
$$\sum_{i=1}^n {P(i)}= \sum_{i=1}^{7}{i^7-(i-1)^{7}}=n^7$$
Therefore $\lambda =0, P(\lambda)=1$

Comment: what?? how do you know $P(i)=i^n-i^{n-1}$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik From the first equation about $P(x)$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{P(i)}=n^7+\lambda, \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{P(i)}={(n-1)}^7+\lambda$ Subtract the two.

Comment: how do you know $P(0)=1$?